# Can the gensim pretrained models be used for doc2vec models?

Tags: python, gensim, word-embedding, doc2vec

I am trying to load a pretrained model [listed here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/howtos/run_downloader_api.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-howtos-run-downloader-api-py) to test the similarity of a handful of paragraphs.

Can gensim's pretrained models only be used with word-level vectors, or can the models also be used for document-length vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the models currently listed there (as of 2020-11-21) are just sets of word-vectors - allowing lookup of vectors, by individual word, but not the full algorithmic model that would allow for followup training. (The only exception I see is the FastText model, which *might8 be a full FastText model, I'm not sure. But even there, the model only reports word-vectors for known words, or synthesizes a vector for out-of-vocabulary words - with no native method of creating vectors for larger texts.)

From any set of word-vectors, there are some crude ways to either create a simple vector for larger texts (such as averaging all the word-vectors for the words of the text together), or do other comparisons between sets of words using the word-vectors to influence the similarity (such as the "[Word Mover's Distance](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_wmd.html)" algorithm, available on Gensim word-vector sets as `wmdistance()`.)

But none of those models availabe via the `gensim.downloader` utility are for algorithms that inherently create vectors for larger texts (such as `Doc2Vec`).

(Separately: I would strongly recommend downloading models explicitly, as data, from their original locations, rather than using the `gensim.downloader` utility. It obscures key aspects of the process, including running extra 'shim' code for each dataset that is downloaded outside of normal code-versioning & package-installation processes, a practice that I consider [recklessly insecure](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2283).)

Comment: Thanks for this great answer! As an add-on, can the corpora here be used to manually train a model?

Comment: Yes, the corpora listed there have been chosen because they may be useful for training models. (But again: I'd recommend explicitly downloading these corpora, or others, direct from their original sources.)